# Sheets importrange matching data from multiple sheets

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script, google-sheets-formula

I have multiply taps in one `sheet A`, each tap has 5000+ rows, some rows have the same content and want to find specific rows, while entering content and copy those rows which are matching to a different `sheet B` and keep the formatting etc from `sheet A.`

**Example:**
I need to make a shipping/order list
I have 2 sheets `Sheet A` is full of information (my stockload), multiply tabs with a lot of rows in each tab. in `Sheet B` (new URL) I want to filter the information.

Lets say, I have 5000 articles spread in 5 tabs on `Sheet A`, someone is ordering 20 articles, so I just want to scan the EAN or any other code on that article to `Sheet B`, and all rows with that data, will be imported. Now I have a brand new list with only the 20 articles, which I can share to the client.

I have tried with script:

```
    function copyRowsWithCopyTo() {
  let spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let sourceSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet0');
  let sourceRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();
  let targetSheet = spreadSheet.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  sourceRange.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(1, 1));
}
```

and also tryng with Importrange query, but I cant seem to figure out the keycode, for searching in all the tabs, and lookup/match the new text/code I always provide.

```
=QUERY(IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hAeUokEf-1DQjRYn2iQXCSCwAoRW-C083z5QYXpzq-Y", "1:1000"), "B2 ",0)
```

[SheetA](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hAeUokEf-1DQjRYn2iQXCSCwAoRW-C083z5QYXpzq-Y/edit#gid=33965345) //// [SheetB](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UsP-W_xD9uo6dWgJjub5HLgB7d_MOB7dEPO7uIz29PY/edit#gid=909633600)

Does anyone know what am I missing?
Thank you

Comment: I think your query should look something like "select Col2 where Col1 = id"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to individually import the data per sheet and combine them into a single array, then put it in a query where you check the `Col2` value if it equates to `B2`. See sample below:

#### EDIT:

- Since you want to check multiple ID inputs for Col2 and Col3, then see the modification below:

#### Formula:

```
=QUERY({
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hAeUokEf-1DQjRYn2iQXCSCwAoRW-C083z5QYXpzq-Y", "Data1!A:P");
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hAeUokEf-1DQjRYn2iQXCSCwAoRW-C083z5QYXpzq-Y", "Data2!A:P");
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hAeUokEf-1DQjRYn2iQXCSCwAoRW-C083z5QYXpzq-Y", "Data3!A:P")
}, "WHERE Col2 = '"&TEXTJOIN("' OR Col2 = '", TRUE, Q:Q)&"' OR Col3 like '"&TEXTJOIN("' OR Col3 like '", TRUE, Q:Q)&"'", 0)
```

#### Output (A4):

[image: output]

Comment: Hi, I have an additional Question. Now the entries comes randomly - sometimes added on top, sometimes at bottom, sometimes in the middle. I guess because it takes the Input from the Location where it is in the Original sheet. Is it possible, that the new entries will always be added only at the bottom?

Comment: @Guhlis, it will not be possible when using this solution. However, you will be able to do it by using script instead. Feel free to post another question for this one.

Comment: I have created the new question. Here you can find it: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71299033/script-data-insert-query-based-on-critera